# Do we HAVE to draw no more than 2.5 mA in USB suspend mode for a device to be enumerated?

Tags: usb, digital-communications

I am currently trying to make an [FT231XS](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/DS_FT231X.pdf) recognised by a Windows 10 computer, and it always says the device is unrecognised as soon as I plug it in (c.f. this other [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/642119/ft231xs-is-not-recognised-by-windows)).

That board is always drawing 12 mA from the USB, in a USB powered configuration. I thought that the "2.5 mA max in suspend mode" rule was only for devices that were intended to keep running in USB suspend mode, but now that I'm desperate I'm wondering if the computer actually tests the compliance to this rule at the time of the enumeration.

Do we actually need to comply with this rule even when we are completely fine with just losing power when the device goes in suspend mode?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is the problem? As opposed to bad wiring, poor signal integrity, or missing drivers, etc.

Comment: It's the only one left, and still something I'd like to know regardless. I've now implemented the minimal circuit, nothing else, on a clean breadboard (from scratch), with clean wiring that I checked 3 times, and measured every single passive before putting them in. For the drivers I've already used the FT4222 without issue and many other FTDI-based cables so I'm investigating every other thing...

Comment: From your schematic in the other question we can see that you have a ferrite bead between the USB connector and the rest of the circuit. Remove it and self-power your device with 5V and then plug it in. If this works then your guess about current consumption might be correct. If it doesn't then you're chasing a red herring here.

Comment: In all likelihood your problem is that you're trying to run USB over a breadboard ... I'd be surprised if that works for anything other than a Low-Speed HID device.

Comment: Well I looked at the signals on a scope and they look clean... I've also tried removing the VCC wire from the breadboard and powered the device externally with 5V. It still does the same thing. This test doesn't answer this specific thread though, since my issue may lie somewhere else.

Comment: Well if you removed the Vcc wire then was USB's Vbus powering anything? If not then it wasn't supplying more than 2.5mA in suspend (or any other mode) and you're still chasing a red herring.

Comment: I don't understand this expression, I'm not a native speaker. The way I see it, if my problem is somewhere else, the fact that the device is not recognised with less than 2.5mA drawn does not mean that the check for <2.5mA is not yet another condition to be enumerated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring

Comment: 1. USB self-powered devices exist - therefore there is no requirement in the spec that you must draw any minimum amount of current in any mode. 2. Since you've apparently operated your device in self-powered mode (by disconnecting Vcc), it's also apparent that your problem is not caused by your device drawing more than 2.5mA (since in that instance it was not drawing any current). Therefore we arrive at the conclusion that chasing this "2.5mA limit in suspend mode" is a "red herring". It has no relevance to the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I agree with that. What I'm saying is that the question still stands unanswered, and I'm curious about the answer, but indeed this test proved that it wasn't the cause of my issue (thanks for the suggestion, I thought there were more differences between the two modes). I'm back to square one in the other thread.

Comment: @user325962 Have you used a USB debugger? I don't see any way suspend behavior could make enumeration fail- a host shouldn't be suspending devices before enumeration. Where were you measuring the signals that they "looked good" on an oscilloscope? At high frequencies you shouldn't assume that signals will look the same on both ends of a long wire...

Comment: @Chris: At the breakout adapter legs. I don't understand though why the signals do appear to have a frequency around 1MHz when this is supposed to be a 12MHz device. Never used a USB debugger, is there a software tool that could give me a log?

Comment: @user325962 Is it 1.5MHz? If so your device is being detected as a low-speed device. Check the impedances of your data lines.

Comment: Yes. The DC resistance is high-Z on both when powered off, which is possible for a high speed device with its pull up switched out when unpowered... Otherwise DP couldn't be high most of the time anyway. But it's supposed to be a full speed device. It's wrecking my brain

Comment: I've analysed USB traffic with USB trace, some things are happening but I don't understand anything. I'll post a link to it in the other thread